# Iterate the number of times of integers value Crystal

Tags: crystal-lang

I'm new to Crystal, and am working through the documentation as I build out a test project to help me reinforce some of the principles inside Crystal.

I need to be able to iterate x number of times in a loop. The x is arbitrary, not tied to an arrays length, but is a set value at the time of the programs execution.

**What's the Crystal way to do this?**

I know that I can setup a `while` and get the behavior I'm looking for, but is there a specific way this is meant to be implemented in Crystal?

For example, in Ruby, you could say `x.times {  }`or in Python you could say `for num in range(x)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an `x.times {}` in Crystal too.

Comment: Why would this not be an appropriate answer?

Comment: I don't see what i did wrong, it seems a perfectly appropriate answer to me? @AhmadF

Comment: Perhaps it's that there isn't an assertion about if this is the convention or "Crystal" way to accomplish this. There's a lot of ways to accomplish what I'm asking. I'm still curious if there's already an accepted standard: I would assume this would be it if there was.

Comment: This is absolutely the correct and standard way to do it. We don't discourage people to use `times` at all.